# Text-text extension for Inkscape in Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: mac, eps, inkscape, epslatex

I need to include LaTeX symbols and equations in Inkscape. I believe the `text text` extension can solve this problem. However I could not see an installation procedure in their website for Mac OS-X. Has anyone installed this extension and make it work with Inkscape in Mac OS-X. I installed the Inkscape in my Mac using `Homebrew- Caskroom`

Comment: I use tex-text in ubuntu. It was simple for me. All I had to do is install pstoedit and voila, it worked. This link was helpful. [http://askubuntu.com/questions/417212/inkscape-with-textext] However, I'm not familiar with MAC

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this problem in [this blog post](https://nicolasamiot.wordpress.com/2013/07/25/inkscape-textext-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/).

You can first download the latest version of the Textext from [here](https://pav.iki.fi/software/textext/) and then you should download and install [the Eggbot extensions](https://code.google.com/archive/p/eggbotcode/downloads) for Inkspace. Copy the two textext file into the extension file of inskspace.

Extension directory is located at:
/Applications/Inkspace.app/Contents/Resources/share/inkspace/extensions/

Now you can use the textext extension on inkspace.

EggBot software can also be found at this [GitHub link.](https://github.com/evil-mad/EggBot/releases/)

Comment: You should put the important part of the answer in the blog to your answer. If the blog goes offline for some reason, people still can find the solution in your answer.

Comment: @512122 Inkspace...?

Comment: Since question already involves inkspace I did not add link to download inkspace.